# Quartus Programmer II TCL flash *.pof file

Tags: tcl, fpga, quartus

Is there a script to upload a `*.pof` file using TCL Scripting through Quartus Programmer on my FPGA?

Preferably from the command line because i want integrate it into my custom software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want a command-line utility you can run `quartus_pgm` like this:

```
quartus_pgm -z --mode=JTAG --operation="p;/path/to/image.sof@2"
```

where `@2` indicates the device in the JTAG chain to program.  You might also be interested in `quartus_jli` which writes JAM files.

For full details look at the [Quartus II Scripting Reference Manual](http://www.altera.co.uk/literature/manual/TclScriptRefMnl.pdf).  I'm not sure whether you can use the `JTAG` package directly from TCL though, the documentation suggests only from a shell in SignalTap (see table 3).

Comment: thanks chiggs, the pof file is supported using this command line?

Comment: @Antonio : I've only used quartus_pgm with *.sof files but poking around a bit I found this "The programmer (quartus_pgm) will use one of the valid supported file format: SOF, POF, jam, and JAM Byte-Code File (.jbc)." so Chiggs solution should work for you.

Comment: Hi Chiggs, Radix, i make the script for my pourpose: quartus_pgm --cable="USB-Blaster [USB-0]" --mode=AS  --option="p;C:\folder\Quartus\file.pof"